# Java: Communicating data from one thread to another

Tags: java, udp

I am working on creating a chat client based on UDP.  The main structure is that there is a server where clients register and where clients can also request to form a connection with another client that is registered with the server.  The clients are structures as follows using pseudo code:

```
public UDPClient() {
    // Create datagram socket

    // Execute RECEIVE thread using datagram socket above
    // Execute SEND thread using datagram socket above
}
```

The idea is to have the send and receive executing on separate threads so I don't get blocked I/O on the receive.  Both of these threads have loops within their run methods that allow you to continually send and receive messages.  The problem I have is this.  If a message comes in on the RECEIVE thread that changes how my SEND should be executing, how do I communicate this to the SEND thread?  Do I have to shoot a datagram off to myself or can I communicate this in the code somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming boths threads have no reference to each other, create a third [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) class, which both read/send threads (classes) reference, that has a `volatile` member field to store the state data you want shared and which has `synchronized` access.

The `volatile` keyword, combined with synchronized access, guarantees that a change made to the field by one thread will be seen by another thread. Without this, changes may not be visible due to the java memory model specification.

#### Edited:

Following "separation of concerns" design guideline, it would be better to *not* have the read/send threads know about each other and to use a third class to orchestrate their activities/behaviour. Add methods to your read/send classes to `stop()`, `start()` etc and call these from the other class.

Using a separate class would also allow:

- Behaviour control by other means, for example a "stop sending" button on an admin web page
- Allowing multiple threads of each type, yet still having proper control through a central point, perhaps using a pool of such threads (without a separate class, you would have a many-to-many nightmare and lots of code that has nothing to do with the job at hand: ie ending and receiving)
- Easier testing of your worker classes, because they do less and are more focused
- porting/embedding them stand-alone for other uses

Comment: I could technically send the thread instances to one another.  Also, I'm wondering if instead of having a singleton class, what if I put member variables in the UDPClient class and pass that instance to each thread when creating it, using "this"?  Then each thread can update/read from those member variables. Would that be a terrible design?

Answer (score 1):

your SEND thread should have public (accesible) method (synchronized if possible) that you should be able to access from your RECEIVE thread. You could use this method to create a boolean flag, string message, etc. that you should always read before you .send(yourPacket); from your SEND thread.

Answer (score 0):

Have a member variable in your READ method that your code can read from and change the SEND method based on that variable.